# close the table view by clicking the button with animation (swift)

Tags: swift

I have created a tableview inside a view controller. I successfully hidden and show the table. However, it doesn't have any animation when it closes and shows the table. i want it to slide out or slide in. the following is my code.

```
   @IBAction func clickButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in


    }) { (finished:Bool) -> Void in
        if(self.tableView.hidden == true){
            self.tableView?.hidden = false
        }
        else{
            self.tableView.hidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animated the `hidden` property of `UIView`. You have to animate the `alpha` property between 0.0 and 1.0 instead. You're also doing your work in the completion block of your animation. You should be doing it in the `animations` block. I also cleaned up the code a little bit. I'm assuming that `tableView` is declared as `UITableView?`, but if it's `UITableView` or `UITableView`, you can omit the `?` when accessing it:

```
@IBAction func clickButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        if self.tableView?.alpha == 1.0 {
            self.tableView?.alpha = 0.0
        }
        else {
            self.tableView?.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }, completion: { (finished:Bool) -> Void in

    })
}
```

Note: you may not want to directly compare `alpha == 1.0`, since [floating point math is hard](http://floating-point-gui.de). Instead, I recommend keeping a local variable, using that to track state, and then base your `alpha` off of that:

```
// Make sure this matches the initial hidden state of your table view.
// So if your table view starts at alpha == 0.0, this should be true.
private var tableViewHidden: Bool = false

@IBAction func clickButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    tableViewHidden = !tableViewHidden
    UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        if tableViewHidden {
            self.tableView?.alpha = 0.0
        }
        else {
            self.tableView?.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }, completion: { (finished:Bool) -> Void in

    })
}
```

Comment: i am new in programming. it there any example of that??

Comment: can i make it to slide out or slide in instead of fading out. i have applied this code and the table will fade out instead of sliding in and out.

Comment: like push and pull

Comment: This would be better suited for a separate question. It sounds like your question, as posted, has been answered. But I'll give you a hint: search for how to animate the `transform` of the table view.

Comment: You should post a new question. Stack Overflow is not a chat room. Also, try googling it ;)